# Rails String Interpolation in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to string interpolate in a **message** model.

I want to combine a string 'message' and a select `media_url` into a `:body` so I can text a text message that contains both a message and a link concatenated. Any help with the interpolation would be appreciated.

I'm trying to do a before_create to grab two fields and combine them into a 3rd field that's saved as body.

My current result yields:

> MESSAGE#{@message.media_url}

*message.rb*

```
before_create do
  self.body = 'MESSAGE' + '#{@message.media_url}'  
end
```

*new.html.erb*

```
<%= f.text_field :body, :value => "body" ,:class => 'form-control ' %>

<%= f.select :media_url, Url.order('name asc').all.collect { |u| [u.name, (u.sanitized_url + u.short_url)] }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

It is suppose to output something like... Message and www.google.com/EdRds which is the value coming from the select box.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `MESSAGE#{@message.media_url}` result, because you're wrapping your `#{}` in single quotes `''`, that must be between double quotes.

You could try just interpolating, not concatenating:

```
before_create do
  # Not an instance variable, the media_url attribute from the object itself
  self.body = "MESSAGE #{self.media_url}" 
end
```

Because `'#{@message.media_url}'` won't work as a interpolation, that must be with double quotes `""`, and `'MESSAGE' +` is concatenating the `@message.media_url` value, so you could wrap all in double quotes and your variable value in `{}`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It helped. However I'm getting
 undefined method `media_url' for nil:NilClass.    media_url has no value because the object hasn't been created. is there a way to get that value from media_url before creation.. or some sort of after create?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see that, being in your model then try accessing your `media_url` value through `self`, `"MESSAGE #{self.media_url}"`.